# Controlling shell stdin from python

Tags: python

I have a custom input method and I have a python module to communicate with it. I'm trying to control the shell with it so everything from local stdout is printed on the remote device and everything sent from the remote device goes into local stdin, so that remote device can control the input given to the program, like if there was an `input` function inside the program the remote device can answer to that too (like in ssh). 
I used python subprocess to control the stdin and stdout:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import thread
from mymodule import remote_read, remote_write
def talk2proc(dap):
    while True:
        try:
            remote_write(dap.stdout.read())
            incmd = remote_read()
            dap.stdin.write(incmd)
        except Exception as e:
            print (e)
            break
while True:
    cmd = remote_read()
    if cmd != 'quit':
        p = Popen(['bash', '-c', '"%s"'%cmd], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
        thread.start_new_thread(talk2proc, (p,))
        p.wait()
    else:
        break
```

But it doesn't work, what should I do?

p.s.
is there a difference for windows?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, I used this for `STDIN`

```
from subprocess import call
call(['some_app', 'param'], STDIN=open("a.txt", "rb"))
```

> a.txt

```
:q
```

This I used for a git wrapper, this will enter the data line wise whenever there is an interrupt in `some_app` that is expecting and user input

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference for Windows. This line won't work in Windows:

```
p = Popen(['bash', '-c', '"%s"'%cmd], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

because the equivalent of `'bash'` is `'cmd.exe'`.